# i need a PHP code to find longest contiguous sequence of characters in the string

Tags: php, algorithm

I need a PHP code to find longest contiguous sequence of characters in the string. So if `b` is coming together for maximum number of times your program should `echo b` and `count`

Example string:

```
aaabababbbbbaaaaabbbbbbbbaa
```

Output must be:

```
b 8
```

Comment: i am able to do this with diffent string which has ',' in it. By using explode function. But my actual problem is this.

Comment: How should it behave for `aaabababbbbbaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa`? 'b' and 'a' are repeated 8 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking for **continuous** sequences:

```
$string = 'aaabababbbbbaaaaabbbbbbbbaa';

$count = strlen($string);
if ($count > 0)
{

    $mostFrequentChar = $curChar = $string[0];
    $maxFreq = $curFreq = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        if ($string[$i] == $curChar)
        {
            $curFreq++;
            if ($curFreq > $maxFreq)
            {
                $mostFrequentChar = $curChar;
                $maxFreq = $curFreq;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $curChar = $string[$i];
            $curFreq = 1;
        }
    }

}

echo $mostFrequentChar . ' ' . $maxFreq;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 5):

Using
- `preg_match_all` to get sequences of repeating characters,
- `array_map` along with `strlen` to get the string length of each sequence
- `max` to get the biggest value in the array.

Consider the following example:

```
$string =  "aaabababbbbbaaaaabbbbbbbbaa";

preg_match_all('#(\w)\1+#',$string,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaa
            [1] => bbbbb
            [2] => aaaaa
            [3] => bbbbbbbb
            [4] => aa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => a
            [3] => b
            [4] => a
        )

)
```

Next we get the sizes for each string of repeating characters

```
$sizes = array_map('strlen', $matches[0]);
print_r($sizes);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 2
)
```

Now let's get the biggest value of the `$sizes` array

```
print max($sizes);
```

Will give us

```
8
```

We need the key for the max value to pick up the letter

```
$maxKey = array_keys($sizes, max($sizes));

print $matches[1][$maxKey[0]];
```

Will output

```
b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'aaabababbbbbaaaaabbbbbbbbaa';
$occurrence = [];

$count = strlen($string);
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
    if(isset($ocurrence[$string[$x]])) {
        $ocurrence[$string[$x]]++;
    } else {
        $ocurrence[$string[$x]] = 0;
    }
}

var_dump($occurrence);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Or if you just want B `asort` the resulting array and get the last element.

Comment: Doesn't this just yield the most frequent character in the string, regardless of continuity? And why do you increment the character instead of the occurrence counter?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This does not answer the question that is asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $x = "aaaaaaabbbbbbbaaaacccccccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaadddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd";
  $count  = strlen($x);

  $y =array();

     $n =0;
     $d =1;
    $first = $x{1};
 for($j = $d;$j < $count;$j++)
 {


        if($x{$j} == $first ) 
        {

        $y[$j] = $x{$j};
        $first = $x{$j}; 

        }
        elseif($x{$j} != $first ) 
        {

        $y[$j] = ",".$x{$j};
        $first = $x{$j}; 

        }



  }

   $xy  =   implode("",$y);
    $xy1     = explode(",",$xy);

     $c_count   = count($xy1);
      $dg = 1;
  for($g = 0;$g < $c_count;$g++) 
  {
       $cnt =   strlen($xy1[$g]); 
       $cntm =   $xy1[$g];
      $replace = $cntm{1};

         if($cnt > $dg)
         {
        $ab = str_replace($cntm,$replace,$cntm);
            $dg = $cnt.".".$ab ;


         }        
  }
   echo $dg;


?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: The code could use some cleaning up as well, for example fix the indenting and remove extra blank lines.